# Wordpress can't login to wp-admin after moving site to subfolder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, migration, subdirectory

I'm new to Wordpress.
Basically I just wanted to move the site from the root www folder to a subfolder.

I have access to the frontend site, but not the admin panel.

I did this steps:

1- Change Wordpress Address URL to http://example.com/subfolder

2- move all files to subfolder, and copy index.php and .htaccess to root folder

3- change index.php code line to `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/m4thod.com2/wp-blog-header.php' );`

4- in .htaccess public_html I tried with this rules but I commented it.

```
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteEngine On
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?m4thod.com$
#RewriteRule ^(/)?$ m4thod.com2[L]
#</IfModule>
```

5- added this lines to wp-config.php

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/subdirectory/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/');

define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/subdirectory/');
```

I don't know if it's the .htaccess file, I have .htaccess in public_html and public_html/subfolder

I normally do this kind of migrations in Magento 2 with Apache server in a VM, but I'm struggling with this hosting and wordpress.
I'm using Blue Host btw.

UPDATE:
I get Interna error 500.
And this is the way I access

https://example.com/subdirectory/wp-login.php

Greetings!

Comment: Please check the file permissions for wp-admin folder.

Comment: Are you able to access the wp-login file? it should be example.com/wp-login.php

Comment: Turns out that this is a bug report on so we can get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conflict arises due to incorrect `.htaccess`. Put the .htaccess file in the root folder and original index.php file copy to the subfolder. without edit `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`
.
Modify the `.htaccess` for the WordPress site in the subdirectory to include the subfolder name. For example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /subdirectory/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score -1):

Please update the permalink setting it works ?

Comment: permalinks only works with frontend in wp not with backend and he is facing the issue only in wp admin